# How long is the process to obtain a French working holiday visa as an Australian?

Tags: visas, france, australian-citizens, working-holiday

I am Australian and looking to obtain a working holiday visa for France. I have read and seen that it takes approximately 2 weeks to get the visa after appointment and sending application. Has anyone gone through the process? If so, how long did it take for you?

Comment: How long would this working holiday be?

Comment: @Flimzy etc - A Working Holiday is a category of visa.  Like Student, Work Permit, etc.  You go for like a year, are eligible to work, but you're not moving there permanently.

Answer (score 3):

I was going to answer, but not being Australian apparently I can't ;)  However I can at least look up some more details for you.

[The French Consulate in Sydney has a link](http://ambafrance-au.org/IMG/pdf/WHM_VVT.pdf) that states 15 days at least.  And judging by other visas I've applied for, I'd cynically expect that to be 15 working days.  At least.

As an aside, I'm annoyed I didn't use more youth working holiday visas before I turned 30.  Why everyone just goes to the UK seems crazy when there are so many other more exotic options.